# Triggering Robot Scripts from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, robotframework

I am new to Robot Framework and I need to trigger my scripts from jenkins. Can someone give me a step by step guide for the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ways Jenkins may access the test data and the ways to trigger Robot Framework scripts from Jenkins are numerous, so I am not sure how useful a step by step guide would be.
Start out simple - use a `Execute shell` or `Execute Windows batch command` build step. The script should read something like 
`python -m robot.run path/to/tests`. The current directory is the root of the workspace.
Typically the tests would be put in the workspace by the Source Code Management configuration of the job.

As you add more and more jobs, you may want to have a common script to invoke Robot Framework, so that common configurations can be extracted out of individual jobs. If you want to always exclude certain tags (e.g. WIP), use a listener, or control where the output goes, using a common script is useful.

I highly recommend adding a post-Build step in the project for the [Robot Framework plugin for Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Robot+Framework+Plugin).

Comment: Thank you for plugin details.

Comment: i just configured jenkins, my sys as slave node. However i have set custom workspace for eg C:\Python27\automation and i in execute shell i am executing " pybot Scripts/KITE/Regression_Suite.txt" . But afer building the project i get error                                                      java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sh" (in directory "C:\Python27\automation\Scripts\KITE\default\Scripts\KITE"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cant find the file specified.                   I dont know why, the scripts are exactly in the same location as 'C:\Python27\automation\Scripts\KITE'.

Comment: Are you using a Execute Shell build step on a Windows node? That might work if you have Cygwin set up, but it is intended for *nix hosts. Maybe you meant to use Execute Windows batch command instead.